# What are React ...Capture events?

Tags: reactjs, dom

There is a duplicate for each event on react `audio` and `video` tags, for example it has `onCanPlayThrough` property and `onCanPlayThroughCapture` as well. Behaviour for both of them in the browser is completely the same.

Do we need to use `...Capture` events instead of standard events? What is the main idea for them? Where can I find information about them.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is covered in the React documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#supported-events), though it's easy to miss:

> The event handlers below are triggered by an event in the bubbling phase. To register an event handler for the capture phase, append `Capture` to the event name; for example, instead of using `onClick`, you would use `onClickCapture` to handle the click event in the capture phase.

DOM events have [multiple phases](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow) (see diagram below), which are (in order):

- Capture
- Target
- Bubbling

Normally we use target or bubbling (`addEventListener`'s `false` third param [the default]), but there are rare occasions where you want to hook into the capture phase instead (third param = `true`). The `...Capture` handlers let you do that.

[image: event flow showing capture from window to target element, then target at element, then bubbling from element back up to window]

Answer (score 2):

They are not the same and the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html) also states this:

> The event handlers below are triggered by an event in the bubbling phase. To register an event handler for the capture phase, append Capture to the event name; for example, instead of using onClick, you would use onClickCapture to handle the click event in the capture phase.

The effect is the same as in regular [DOM bubbling/capturing](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link4). If you want to capture, the event will fire on a parent first. On bubbling it will fire on the actual element first and then bubble to parents.

Comment: What would be a use case for the capture phase instead of the bubbling phase?